# How to use Distinct Function through PHP in displaying unique value

Tags: php, mysql

how to display only Distinct values through PHP - so that the resultant output is unique

The distinct function is not having any impact on this line

```
#__new_categories.cat_name as cat_name
```

Here is the complete code

```
    <?php
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $c = $item->prod_cat_id;

    $query = "SELECT
  DISTINCT  #__new_categories.cat_name as cat_name
   , #__new_categories.cat_parent as cat_parent
   , #__new_products.prod_name  as prod_name
 from #__new_categories 
 inner join #__new_products on #__new_products.prod_cat_id = #__new_categories.id
  where #__new_products.prod_cat_id = $c";

    $db->setQuery($query);                                  
    $results = $db->loadObjectList();  
    foreach($results as $row){
       echo $row->cat_name;
    }
     ?>
```

When echoing in cat_name is displaying similar values like

Honda Honda Honda Honda Honda Honda

Ford Ford Ford Ford Ford Ford

How to use Distinct Function in

```
echo $row->cat_name;
```

Comment: Why don't you use the distinct function from mysql ?

Comment: why not use the Distinct function into your sql query?

Comment: @VasilShaddix,ac.freelancer - Question edited. Pl see distinct as used in. Its having no impact

Comment: @Ruchika Why do you use inner join ? That is your problem.

Comment: Is it not possible then to get unique output due to inner join ?

Comment: @Ruchika you can check out my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from the `inner join`.

You can do something like this with your query:

`GROUP BY #__new_categories.cat_name`

or to handle this with PHP, because this will most probably break your query:

```
$results = $db->loadObjectList();  
$uniqueValues = array();
foreach($results as $row){
    if (!isset($uniqueValues[$row->cat_name])) {
        echo $row->cat_name;
        $uniqueValues[$row->cat_name] = true;
    }
}
```